# Define Custom Route asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to assign a route in asp.net mvc application.

What i have is a Measurement Controller. I have 3 types of Measurement in the business scenario.

1. Blouse
2. Lhenga
3. Pardi

Due to which i wanted the url to be like **Measurement/Create/Lhenga**

Just like this, I want to create **Measurement/Create/Blouse** and **Measurement/Create/Pardi**  routes.

Although I know I will have to write a route in RouteConfig.cs class.
I have written

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "MeasurementRoute",
            "{controller}/{action}/{type}/"
            );
```

Comment: Its not really clear what you want `Lhenga` is supposed to be, (you certainly cannot have 2 action methods in a route) but best guess is that you want `routes.MapRoute( name: "MeasurementRoute", url: "Measurement/Create/{Lhenga}" defaults: new { controller = "Measurement", action = "Create" });` where the method is `public ActionResult Create(string lhenga)` and if you navigate to `../Measurement/Create/Blouse` then the value of `lhenga` will be "Blouse"

Comment: @StephenMuecke . Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the question. Please refer to it now.

Comment: Have you tried: [Route("Measurement/Create/Lhenga")] for particular method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

     routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Contact",
      url: "Contact",
      defaults: new {
       controller = "Contact", action = "Address"
      });

     routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new {
       controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
      }
     );
    }
```

Every MVC application must configure (register) at least one route, which is configured by MVC framework by default

You can also configure a custom route using MapRoute extension method. You need to provide at least two parameters in MapRoute, route name and url pattern. The Defaults parameter is optional.
You can register multiple custom routes with different names. Consider the following example where we register "Contact" route.

As shown in the above code, URL pattern for the Contact route is Contacts/{id}, which specifies that any URL that starts with domainName/Contacts, must be handled by ContactController. Notice that we haven't specified {action} in the URL pattern because we want every URL that starts with Contact should always use Index action of ContactController. We have specified default controller and action to handle any URL request which starts from domainname/Contacts.

MVC framework evaluates each route in sequence. It starts with first configured route and if incoming url doesn't satisfy the URL pattern of the route then it will evaluate second route and so on. In the above example, routing engine will evaluate Contact route first and if incoming url doesn't starts with /Contacts then only it will consider second route which is default route